# jQuery ui google map check if marker is in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/

I am trying to find a way when looping through markers, of finding out if the markers are visible within the current viewport.

Does anybody know how to do this. I have tried isVisible()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the beta version there is a inViewport, see [jquery google maps plugin filter by property](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-filtering.html)

Comment: I've seen this site before, however it has been updated since. This is useful for other people however I have found my own answer. Thank you very much for your time and input, I hope other people will find this post / question useful.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about jquery-ui-map, but in the raw [google maps api v3](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) it's fairly simple:

```
var bnd = map.getBounds();
var ne = bnd.getNorthEast();
var sw = bnd.getSouthWest();
var pos = marker.getPosition();
if (pos.lat() >= sw.lat() && pos.lat() <= ne.lat() &&
    pos.lng() >= sw.lng() && pos.lng() <= ne.lng()) { // marker is in view
    ....
}
```

Comment: what about it the view changes I.E. someone zooms in and pans the viewport?

Comment: never mind last comment was redundant. I made a minor error in my code. Sorry to waste everyones time with useless comments.